# REST services - Flag to force PUT and POST to return the record instead of nothing?

Tags: rest

I'm updating a record in a list via a PUT to the '_vti_bin/listdata.svc' service.

When I initially POST the data, I get the list item I posted back from SharePoint, with a timestamp, etc.

When I PUT the updated data, I'm getting no response body back from the server (just the HTTP 204 - No Content response).  Is there a way to force these serves to send me the item, so I can get the timestamp or other calculated field values?